# TypeScript: How to keep type safety when cast to generic field-value type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm writing a function which converts objects from original to target format using `metadata` object that describes mapping rules.

This metadata contains the list of fields in target objects and a way of how to get field values from the source object. It should support both string representations of the path to target fields and functions which take source object and return some value.

Something like this:

```
type Metadata<F> = {
    [field: string]: string | ((data: F) => any);
}
```

The goal is to have an ability to build metadata like this:

```
interface Message {
    id: string;
    date: number;
}

const messageMetadata: Metadata<Message> = { msgId: 'id', msgDate: (m) => new Date(m.date) };
```

The problem here is that the `messageMetadata` object is not type safe. I can access not only to declared fields `msgId` and `msgDate`, but to anything I write:

```
console.log(messageMetadata.msgId);           // 'id'
console.log(messageMetadata.msgDate);         // (m) => new Date(m.date)
console.log(messageMetadata.undeclaredField); // undefined  <<<<<<< This works but shouldn't
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```js
type MetadataLike<F, T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: string | ((data: F) => any);
}

const defineMetadata = <F>() => <T extends MetadataLike<F, T>>(metadata: T): T => metadata;


interface Message {
  id: string;
  date: number;
}

const messageMetadata = defineMetadata<Message>()({ msgId: 'id', msgDate: (m) => new Date(m.date) });
```

---

## How does it work?

To understand it, we start from a minimal solution.

```js
type MetadataLike<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: string | ((data: any) => any);
}

const defintMetadata = <T extends MetadataLike<T>>(metadata: T): T => metadata;


interface Message {
  id: string;
  date: number;
}

const messageMetadata = defintMetadata({ msgId: 'id', msgDate: (m) => new Date(m.date) });
```

The compiler infers `T` from the given argument and knows that the argument and return value have the same type. The constraint `<T extends MetadataLike<T>>` ensures each key in `T` is either a `string` or `(data: F) => any`.

One caveat is that `data` has type `any`. We can give the type explicitly by using `(m: Message) => new Date(m.date)` and call it a day.

If you want `m` to be typed `Message` automatically, we have to write it somewhere else.

```js
type MetadataLike<F, T> = {
  [P in keyof T]: string | ((data: F) => any);
}

const defintMetadata = <F, T extends MetadataLike<F, T>>(metadata: T): T => metadata;


interface Message {
  id: string;
  date: number;
}

const messageMetadata = defintMetadata<Message>({ msgId: 'id', msgDate: (m) => new Date(m.date) });
```

But TypeScript rejects it with error `Expected 2 type arguments, but got 1`. We cannot give it one type parameter and ask it to infer the other one.

The workaround is to create a generic function which returns a generic function. We give `Message` to the first function and the function amend the type constraint of the returned function.